# Iphone third generation

Tags: iphone, password

I have and iphone three and I forgot the password on it and it didn't work when i went to restore it. I really need to get back on it again.

Answer (score 1):

It can happen one forgets the password.

Apple knows that and has made every effort to help you with recovering it.

The quickest way is to go to [Apple website](https://iforgot.apple.com/password/verify/appleid) and request password reset.

It is a Automated process, and you will receive a email from Apple, so look for it.

There is more help here https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201487